# Filter for certain values in a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON Object like this:

```
 var test = {"employees": [
    {"name":"John","klasse":12,"fach":"BW"},
    {"name":"max", "klasse":13,"fach":"E"},
    {"name":"Stef","klasse":14,"fach":"D"},
    {"name":"abc", "klasse":15,"fach":"AM"},
    {"name":"def", "klasse":17,"fach":"AM"},
    {"name":"John","klasse":12,"fach":"D"}
]};
```

In my HTML file I have 3 input fields, which should give me the values to search in the JSON object.

```
<form ng-controller="Suche">
    <span>Suchbegriff: </span><input type="text" ng-model="suchbegriff"> <br>
    <span>Klasse: </span><input type="text" ng-model="klasse"> <br>
    <span>Fach: </span><input type="text" ng-model="fach"> <br>

    <input type="submit" ng-click="submit()">

    <input type="submit" ng-click="sort()" value="Sort">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Klasse</td>
            <td>Fach</td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="result in results">
            <td>{{result.name}}</td>
            <td>{{result.klasse}}</td>
            <td>{{result.fach}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-hide="filter" ng-repeat="erg in json.employees">
            <td>{{erg.name}}</td>
            <td>{{erg.id}}</td>
            <td>{{erg.fach}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Now my Problem. For instance I want search for the name "John" and fach "D". 
My current output would be the following:

[image]

As you can see I don´t get the output I want. It should only list the third row with name "John" klasse "12" and fach "D".

How can I fix this problem?

This is my function so far:

```
 $scope.submit = function () {
    $scope.results = [];

    var searchField = "name",
        searchField2 = "klasse",
        searchField3 = "fach";

    var search          = $scope.suchbegriff,
        search_class    = $scope.klasse,
        search_subject  = $scope.fach;

    if(
        search_subject == null || search_subject == ''
        && search == null || search == ''
        && search_class == null || search_class == ''
    ) {
        $scope.filter = false;
    }

    for (var i=0 ; i < test.employees.length ; i++) {
        if (
            test.employees[i][searchField] == search ||
            test.employees[i][searchField2] == search_class ||
            test.employees[i][searchField3] == search_subject
        ) {
            $scope.filter = true;
            $scope.results.push(test.employees[i]);
        } 
    }
};
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the `for...` loop, you are pushing employees that match either of the search criteria instead of pushing those that match all the search criteria provided. Try the following:

```
 $scope.submit = function () {
    $scope.results = [];

    var searchField = "name",
        searchField2 = "klasse",
        searchField3 = "fach";

    var search          = $scope.suchbegriff,
        search_class    = $scope.klasse,
        search_subject  = $scope.fach;

    var hasSearch          = !(search == null || search == ''),
        hasSearch_class    = !(search_class == null || search_class == ''),
        hasSearch_subject  = !(search_subject == null || search_subject == '');

    $scope.filter = hasSearch || hasSearch_class || search_subject;

    for (var i=0 ; i < test.employees.length ; i++) {
        if (
            (!hasSearch || test.employees[i][searchField] == search) &&
            (!hasSearch_class || test.employees[i][searchField2] == search_class) &&
            (!hasSearch_subject || test.employees[i][searchField3] == search_subject)
        ) {
            $scope.results.push(test.employees[i]);
        } 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this pen I've created.
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/manishsingh10895/pen/wgWLZM?editors=1010)

```
app.filter('employeeFilter', function() {
return function(input, name, k, f) {
name = name.toLowerCase();
k = k.toLowerCase();
f = f.toLowerCase();`

return input.filter(function(item) {
   return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(name) && item.klasse.toString().includes(k) && item.fach.toLowerCase().includes(f);
});
```

}
})

These kind of things are easier if left to filters. You're using three parameters, so, I don't think that angular's default filter would be of any use. You can make your own simply. See the filter in the pen.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ahh I see, it is a very nice solution for my problem. I have never heared about Angular filters before, so I tried it my way. Thank you for the nice solution! It helped me a lot!